# Flutter Text inside Text Field becoming white automatically for iOS Dark mode

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, textfield, darkmode

When I am using iOS dark mode. Then flutter Text field text color is not visible. How to solve this problem ?

Comment: Did you override any themes? also Please post the theme data which is given in MaterialApp.

Comment: Yes ! I override light theme to dark theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this could work if you use Colors.black as text color. I guess the Cupertino template uses CupertinoColors.black as text color but not the equivalent for the background. Even though this color is called black, it turns white in dark mode. I think this is not the case with Material colors. Otherwise define your own black color with RGB - or even better, use CupertinoColors.white as background (as it will turn black)